# Proto004 - no output at all for the new proto004 baker and endorser

Tags: upgrade

Is this "normal"?  When running my new proto004 endorser and baker in prep for the upcoming upgrade, my logs simply say:

```
Waiting for the node to be synchronized with its peers...
Node synchronized.
```

And nothing else.  Its pretty disconcerting.  Is that normal?
Maybe next time we do an upgrade they can give us a little bit of output there to get us all some warm fuzzies there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  It is waiting for the switch over to the new protocol(Athens).  Once the network switches over the 003's will turn off and the 004's will start up.